# Can't connect to vsftpd, not even from localhost

Tags: raspberry-pi, vsftpd, raspbian

I have installed *vsftpd* on Raspbian by following steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install vsftpd`
2. I altered a few settings by calling `sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf`
3. Restarted by `sudo service vsftpd restart`

No errors so far. The problem, however, does not even seem to be a matter of the settings - I can't connect on port 20 no matter what. It acts like any other unused port.

If I try to connect self:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ telnet 127.0.0.1 20
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

And, on windows telnet:

```
Microsoft Telnet> o 192.168.0.244 20
Připojování k 192.168.0.244...Nelze navázat spojení s hostitelem. na portu 20: P
řipojení se nezdařilo
Microsoft Telnet>
```

<sub>Sorry, it's Czech, but it just says it can't connect.</sub>

There is no delay between calling and getting the error message.

I can't check if it runs on another port, however, it runs for sure, because `netstat -a | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'` gives me this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:ftp                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9405     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2517     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     497      /run/udev/control
```

However `:ftp` is pretty useless to check if the port is or isn't 20.

Comment: If you had also used the netstat -n option your confusion would have cleared as it shows the actual port number and not the default service for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try port 21. That is the standard-ftp-port, not port 20, 20 is default for ftp-data.

Comment: Ah damn... Yes, you're right.